# Rails grid view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yii2

I trying Ruby on Rails after Yii2 and my question is:
is there something like yii2 grid view? Yii2 lets me make admin panel faster and useful for searching content with filters.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to make `.row`s and `.col`s for formatting.

You can use [ActiveAdmin](https://activeadmin.info/) for generating admin interfaces quit easily though, even easier than Yii2.

Here is a tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?autoplay=true